# Stripe - create invoice items and send invoice via e-mail to connected account

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I create invoice item for every worker against job.

```
$product= $stripe->products->create(['name' => $job->name]);
            $price =  $stripe->prices->create([
            'product' => $product['id'],
            'unit_amount' => $amount,
            'currency' => 'gbp',
            ]);
    
$items = $stripe->invoiceItems->create([
         'customer' => $user->customer_id,
         'price'=>$price['id']
          ]);
```

i need to send invoice on specific date.
when company pay invoice automatically transfer to connected account for every invoice items.
but its send to all invoice items in invoice to one connected account

```
$invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::create([
      'customer' => $customer_id,
      'application_fee_amount' => 10,
    ], ['stripe_account' => '{{CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID}}']);
                
$response= $stripe->invoices->sendInvoice($inovice['id'],[]);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As noted above, please clarify the question and what you are trying to accomplish and I would be happy to help!

Comment: 1- save different invoices against connected account
2- send all invoice as total to a customer after a month
3- when customer pay invoice total after month it will automatically transfer to connect account